# Application rating function in android

Tags: android

I have developed an Android application.I want to add a rating functionality to it.So that user can rate my app in android market(google Play).Can anyone tell me how to do it with rating bar widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible to let the user rate an app in the Play store from within your application. You will need to open the app's Play store page and let the user rate it from there.